# Integrating pyejabberd with django api to make ejabberd user registration

Tags: python, django, api, xmpp, ejabberd

i am using django rest framework for making API. I have to integrate django with ejabberd xmpp to register users with ejabberd and get thier jabber id (JID). I came across pyejabberd which provided fucnctionality to register user with ejabberd. I need to know how to integrate it with my django project . The link to pyejabberd is -

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyejabberd

I tried to include it in installed apps to to use it after importing. I am also not sure whether we can use pyejabberd with django or not. Any help will be highly appreciated .

Is there any other library to use if we want to register users with ejabberd and obtain JID in django

Comment: I'm also looking for the same solution. Did you find anything?